# Active Pattern Matching with Discriminated Unions

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union, active-pattern

Is there any way to use a discriminated union of the following form with active pattern matching? I haven't been able to find any examples.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
type c = a | b

type foo =
  | bar1
  | bar2 of c

//allowed
let (|MatchFoo1|_|) aString =
  match aString with
  | "abcd" -> Some bar1
  | _ -> None

//not allowed
let (|MatchFoo2|_|) aString =
  match aString with
  | "abcd" -> Some (bar2 of a)
  | _ -> None
```

Why can "Some" not be used in the second way? Is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: When constructing values you don't need `of`: `"abcd" -> Some (bar2 a)`

Comment: @Lee Oh wow, that was a really small mistake. Thank you! You should submit that as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to use `of` when declaring the type, so you can just construct values with the `bar2` constructor like:

```
bar2 a
```

Your second function should work if you change it to:

```
let (|MatchFoo2|_|) aString =
  match aString with
  | "abcd" -> Some (bar2 a)
  | _ -> None
```